# Determine most recent 'vote type' for a record, returning 2 fields for HasVotedUp/Down?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 table containing 'votes'. They are either a 'VoteUp' or 'VoteDown' `VoteTypeId` (1 or 2 respectively).

Each vote has a timestamp of when the vote was inserted in the table.
Each vote row belongs to a post (FK `PostId`).
Each vote row belongs to a user (FK `UserId`).

I have a query to bring back a list of posts, and in that same query, I want to identify if the current user has voted that post up or down (or not at all).

In some cases, a single post may contain both an Up AND a Down vote, where the user changed their mind at a later date (changing a Down vote to an Up vote). In this scenario, I want to identify the latest vote as being the relevant vote (the original down vote is simply held in the DB for historic purposes).

Ideally, I'd like 2 simple BIT fields returned within the Query: `HasVotedUp` and `HasVotedDown`.

I *could* include something like this (cut down for brevity), to simply return whether the most recent vote for that user/post is an Up or Down vote, then assign the 'HasVotedUp' and 'HasVotedDown' properties in code based on the returned VoteTypeId...

```
select p.id, p.body,
(select top 1 votetypeid from votes where userid = 1 and postid = p.id order by creationdate desc) as CurrentVoteTypeId
from posts p
```

... but I wondered if there was a similarly simple (but importantly, efficient) approach that I could use to return the 2 'HasVotedUp/Down' fields within the query, so it's on a plate, ready to use?

This nested approach was all I came up with so far but I'm sure this is inefficient?!

```
select cast((select count(1)
             from   votes
             where  userid = 1
                    and postid = p.id
                    and votetypeid = 1
                    and creationdate > (select creationdate
                                        from   votes
                                        where  userid = 1
                                               and postid = p.id
                                               and votetypeid = 2)) as bit) as
       HasVotedUp,
       cast((select count(1)
             from   votes
             where  userid = 1
                    and postid = p.id
                    and votetypeid = 2
                    and creationdate > (select creationdate
                                        from   votes
                                        where  userid = 1
                                               and postid = p.id
                                               and votetypeid = 1)) as bit) as
       HasVotedDown
from   posts p
```

Comment: SQL Server? What version? Also, we need to see a bit more of your query - I'm guessing what you've shown us is in the SELECT clause of your main query?

Comment: Sorry, it's SQL Server 2008. Yes, those snippets are from within the SELECT clause of the main query, which itself just selects * from posts (to keep things simpler). I'll update my question slightly. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `and creationdate > ` bits are needed for in your final query? It seems to be only including `HasVotedUp/Down` if the user previously did the opposite?

Comment: My thinking behind that part is to ensure that if there is both a down and up vote, we only want to return a count of 1 if that votetype is the more recent of the vote rows (so it'll either return a 1 or 0, which is what I want for both of these columns). If I exclude the creationdate >, both of these nested queries will return a 1 (i.e, the user currently has an upvote AND downvote, which is a conflict in the logic I want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be very scalable:

```
select p.id,
    CASE WHEN vt.votetypeid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasVotedUp,
    CASE WHEN vt.votetypeid = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasVotedDown
from posts p left outer join
    (
        select v.postid, v.votetypeid
        from votes v inner join
        (
            select postid, userid, max(creationdate) as creationdate
            from votes
            group by postid, userid
        ) newest on v.postid = newest.postid and v.userid = newest.userid and v.creationdate = newest.creationdate
        where v.userid = 1
    ) vt on p.id = vt.postid
```

Answer (score 1):

Any good to you?

```
SELECT p.id,
       O.*
FROM   posts p
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(CASE
                                 WHEN RN = 1 THEN votetypeid
                               END)            AS currentvotetypeid,
                           ISNULL(MAX(CASE
                                        WHEN votetypeid = 1 THEN 1
                                      END), 0) AS HasVotedUp,
                           ISNULL(MAX(CASE
                                        WHEN votetypeid = 2 THEN 1
                                      END), 0) AS HasVotedDown
                    FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY creationdate DESC) RN,
                                   *
                            FROM   votes
                            WHERE  userid = 1
                                   AND postid = p.id) T) O
```

Comment: This initially looked like it worked but then I noticed one or two records that were coming back with a 'true' for both VoteUp & VoteDown. I've tested Hallainzil's solution below and it's equally fast and is showing the expected results. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Yep, those results were to be expected as I still don't understand what you are trying to do but figured you should be able to apply some combination of the columns to get what ever you are trying to do.